# Как перезагрузить страницу в react, сохранив props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня большая формочка с разными инпутами, в том числе с загрузкой файла.
Мне нужно при нажатии кнопки изменить this.state и перезагрзить страницу так чтобы все инпуты очистились, пропал элемент страницы(его наличие привязано к state) и при этом сохранились все props, в них лежит функция и элемент.
У меня есть функция refresh, которая изменяет стейт и она же должна обновить страницу.

Comment: Если вам нужны данные после полной перезагрузки страницы, то вам нужно записывать их в local storage, а при инициализации компонента присваивать эти данные в стейт